# Migrating from RxJava1 to RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I was looking at the example of an android app coded in MVP ([link here](http://hannesdorfmann.com/mosby/first-app/)). But now I want to recode the given RxJava1 code in the tutorial to an RxJava2 code. However, I am having trouble with it especially `unSubscribe()` and `isUnSubscribed()`. I tried to convert it and I will share my attempt.

**RxJava1 Code:**

```
  public void doLogin(AuthCredentials credentials) {
    cancelSubscription();
    subscriber = new Subscriber<Account>() {
      @Override public void onCompleted() {
        if (isViewAttached()) {
          getView().loginSuccessful();
        }
      }

      @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
        if (isViewAttached()) {
          getView().showError();
        }
      }

      @Override public void onNext(Account account) {
        eventBus.post(new LoginSuccessfulEvent(account));
      }
    };

    // do login
    accountManager.doLogin(credentials)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(subscriber);
  }
  private void cancelSubscription() {
    if (subscriber != null && !subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
      subscriber.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

**This is my attempt on RxJava2 Code:**

```
  public void doLogin(AuthCredentials credentials) {
    cancelSubscription();
    subscriber = new Subscriber<Account>() {

      @Override public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        // do login
        accountManager.doLogin(credentials)
                      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                      .subscribe(subscriber);
      }

      @Override public void onCompleted() {
        if (isViewAttached()) {
          getView().loginSuccessful();
        }
      }

      @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
        if (isViewAttached()) {
          getView().showError();
        }
      }

      @Override public void onNext(Account account) {
        eventBus.post(new LoginSuccessfulEvent(account));
      }
    };
  }


  private void cancelSubscription() {   
    //isUnsubscribed and unsubscribe doesnt work anymore
  }
```

I am fairly new to the concept of RxJava. If anyone can point out my mistakes and guide me that would be great. :)

Comment: Please read the [What's different](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0) wiki page. Your case is covered in [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subscriber) section.

Comment: Yes i know. I already solved the issue. Will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for the late answer. Have been extremely busy. As stated by @akarnokd there have been made a lot of changes in RxJava2 as compared to RxJava1. For those who interested please look at this [video](https://realm.io/news/gotocph-jake-wharton-exploring-rxjava2-android/).

As far as the above question is concerned, we can achieve the same by using `DisposableObservables`

Here is the answer to the above question. I have tested it and it works.

```
public void doLogin(AuthCredentials credentials) {
     myDisposableObserver = new DisposableObserver<Account>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(Account account) {
                    eventBus.post(new LoginSuccessfulEvent(account));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    if (isViewAttached()) {
                        getView().showError();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    if (isViewAttached()) {
                        getView().loginSuccessful();
                    }
                }
            };

            // do login
            accountManager.doLogin(credentials)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(subscriber);
        }
    }

    private void cancelSubscriptionToMyPrescriptorManager() {
        if (myDisposableObserver != null && !myDisposableObserver.isDisposed()) {
            myDisposableObserver.dispose();
        }
    }
```